# If $w$, $x$, $y$, and $z$ are real numbers with $w < x$ and $y < z$, is the cardinality of the closed interval $[w,x]$ the same as that of $[y,z]$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

My reasoning is yes. I tried to draw a few example functions and based on my workings, think that the answer should be yes but I couldn't figure out how exactly I should mathematically prove the fact. Any hints?

Comment: Is it possible to find a bijection (injective and surjective function) between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

You can build a linear mapping $f:[w,x]\to[y,z]$ such that $f(w) = y$ and $f(x) = z$.

Precisely, if we let $f(t) = at + b$, it results into the following system:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
aw + b = y\\\\
ax + b = z
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider the case where $[w,x] = [0,1]$ and $f\colon [0,1] \to [y,z]$ is defined by $$f(t) = tz + (1-t)y$$

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The most basic method to prove two sets having the same cardinality is by constructing a bijection.

For that, define a function f mapping [w,x] to [y,z]. A sufficient condition for f to be a bijection is simply that f be continuous and increasing.

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful!